# Middleman images/fonts from bower

Tags: bower, middleman, compass

I'm wondering what the best way is to use images & fonts from bower packages with middleman. As an example, I'm trying to add the [slick.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) carousel to my project. It's on bower and includes css, js, images, and fonts in the bower code.

With middleman, I have things set up where I've added the bower_components directory to the path for sprockets and compass, so the scss and js files are getting compiled correctly and working fine.

But the images and fonts aren't getting put anywhere where they'll be used. The slick.js library uses scss and is set up to use the compass `image-url` and `font-url` functions if they exist, meaning I need to somehow get the assets from the bower_components directory to be served from the same place as all my own images and fonts, and in a way that works in both the development `middleman server` mode as well as when running build.

How do I do this?

Obviously possible solutions are just to vendorize the slick.js library directly into my code or include it from the cdn where it's already hosted and not worry about not having it compiled into my single css and js files. Either could work fine but I'm wondering about the general case, surely this is common scenario for anyone using bower and middleman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out - I thought compass was for requiring scss files and sprockets was just for the js, but middleman also uses sprockets (the `middleman-sprockets` library) for copying arbitrary static assets.

It's a bit manual and verbose (if there were a lot more files middleman suggests writing a script to auto-discover them by file extension types and import them) but my solution is to include the following in the `config.rb` file:

```
# set local vars I'll need to access later
images_dir = 'images'

set :images_dir, images_dir

# ... other config 

sprockets.import_asset('slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif') {|p| "#{images_dir}/ajax-loader.gif"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use grunt, but it's the same issue. Generally you have the following options:

-Commit what you need in the bower_components directory right in to source control and reference your resources from there (somewhat recommended especially if something external is down when you are doing a build), or if you don't like exposing bower_components in URLs, create a route that directs to your bower_components folder

-Copy components on build/middleman script execution to a specified path. There will be no resources to check in for this option, you just choose a destination to reference in your code and have middleman copy your components out there.